# Does Lost Planet 2 have PC/Xbox 360 cross-platform multiplayer?

Tags: lost-planet-2

Will the PC version of *Lost Planet 2* be able to play multiplayer against the Xbox Live community, like you could with the first version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, I'm afraid the multiplayer in LP2 is same platform only.  That applies across all formats.